# autocompletion - set iskeyword disabling highlights

Tags: syntax-highlighting, autocompletion, keyword

I have set up some syntax highlights for some patterns, for example: `sc.nextInt()` nextInt will be highlighted as a Function...  Then I have included `:set iskeyword+=(,.,)` in order for autocompletion to offer completions with brackets and dots in popups, but these settings disable any set highlights around the newly set keywords. (nextInt() will no be highlighted anymore etc.) I was wondering if there is a better solution or a way to go around this.

Comment: Use `:syntax match` instead of `:syntax keyword` if you’re concerned about `iskeyword` affecting the syntax-keywords.

Comment: I use ```autocmd Syntax * syntax match Function "\v<%(\h|\$)%(\w|\$)*>\ze\_s*\(\_.{-}\)" containedin=CONTAINED```

Comment: This is the little trouble. The big one is that it changes the behaviour of `w`,`b` and so on.

Comment: I have managed to make it work by adding the defined highlight groups to syn iskeyword. I just have to figure out if this is a valid solution.